# Linking in Linux - looking for explanation

Tags: c, linux, compilation, linker, codeblocks

If there was someone that could explain to me the whole process involved in compiling and the functions of the linker (all this "programming backscene work"), which could make ​​me realize the whole scheme. It would be thankful.

The error is "undefined reference to menu()"

I'm on Linux and use codeblocks to program in C. All files are in the same folder.

I have now 3 files:

maintest.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "biblioteca.h"
int main() {
    menu(2, "opçao 1", "opçao 2");
}
```

biblioteca.h

```
#ifndef _BIBLIOTECA_H_
#define _BIBLIOTECA_H_

#define null '\0'
typedef enum { false, true } boolean;
typedef unsigned short uint;
typedef char* string;


void menu(int count, ...);

#endif
```

biblioteca.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "biblioteca.h"

void menu(int count, ...) {
    va_list listPointer;
    va_start(listPointer, count);
    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        char *string = va_arg(listPointer, char*);
        line(1, 1);;
        printf("%d ..... %s", i < count ? i : 0 , string);
    }
    va_end(listPointer);
}
```

If somebody could just give this a shot and explain to me what is happening and why aren't the files linking each other, I would appreciate.

Comment: Files don't "link each other" unless you tell them to (by default only the standard C and Unix library is linked in). Please show the commands you used to compile and link the program.

Comment: What command-line did you use to compile the program? Did you actually include `biblioteca.c` in the linking step?

Comment: I've just created the 3 files, the ones you see, and then build/compile/run. I used to do this on windows and it wasn't a problem. That's why I'm asking if you could explain to me or give me some links that can explain that in easy terms since I'm a beginner.
I don't use the terminal to compile, I'm learning linux yet. But I appreciate the attention so far

Comment: Are you perchance compiling anything in C++ mode? This could happen, for example, if a filename ends with ".C" (capital C) instead of lowercase C.

Comment: I'm not a Code::Blocks user, but I'm sure I've seen problems with it because of nneonneo's point before -- not because of file names, but simply because of how the IDE is configured.

Comment: Could it be it was dark and your eyes were tired and therfore you accidently read `undefined reference to menu()` instead of `undefined reference to line()`? ;-)

Comment: ahah, no sir. That's a great catch but I just put here a small sample of the code that had the same issue as the rest. So that's not the problem so far :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is "undefined reference to menu()" may be IDE Linker issue or you may not properly Link

there is one issue in the second file  `stdlib.h` consists  inclusion of `sys/types.h`  on demand and this header file consists of this type defination

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
```

In your header file also you have same thing.

so because of this you will get an error of `conflicting types`

this can be avoided by removing inclusion of header file in the second file or else you can remove inclusion stdlib.h (this is not recommended).

If you use Linux.please try this with GCC.use -Wall option to check is there any warnings. intentionally commented line(1,1); because of undifined reference to line in GCC.make sure that your three files are in same  directory where you compiling your code. other wise you need to give absolute paths of the files.

```
 gcc -Wall maintest.c  biblioteca.c -o result   

./result
```

maintest.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "biblioteca.h"
int main() {
    menu(2, "opÃ§ 1", "opÃ§ 2");
}
```

biblioteca.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void menu(int count, ...) {
    int i;
    va_list listPointer;
    va_start(listPointer, count);
    for( i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        char *string = va_arg(listPointer, char*);
    //    line(1, 1);
        printf("%d ..... %s", i < count ? i : 0 , string);
    }
    va_end(listPointer);
}
```

biblioteca.h

```
#ifndef _BIBLIOTECA_H_
#define _BIBLIOTECA_H_

#define null '\0'
typedef enum { false, true } boolean;
typedef unsigned short uint;
typedef char* string;

void menu(int count, ...);

#endif
```

Comment: Uh, what? He's using an IDE, not the command line; he's running into a linker error not a compiler error; and your answer is unfortunately rather poorly written.

Comment: @nneonneo i am sorry, if there is any worng.as he is on Linux. he have chance of using Gcc.thats why i was suggested this solution.and at least removing header file inclusion in second file would be helpful.

Comment: `biblioteca.h` carries "header-guards", so multiple inclusion could not be an issue. Above this not including the module header into the module itself seem somewhat arkward to me. And finally "*"undefined reference to ...*" definitly is a linker error.

Comment: @nneonneo What is your problem. It worth a try compiling and linking from the command line. If it works, one can at least be sure that there is some misconfiguration in the IDE.

Comment: @alk thanks for pointing header guards.Noticed this header guard **#ifndef** and modified my answer.

Comment: @Tim thanks. As he is using LINUX , he have an option to use Gcc.This would be fine if he get rid of this with GCC and he can say there would be an issue with the code blocks IDE.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried the command line.

the instructions you gave me for terminal compiling resulted in "nothing happens", neither the program itself. But when I do:
gcc -Wall -o maintest.c biblioteca.c -std=c99
it gives me the same "undefined reference to" problem that appears on codeblocks. So I don't know how to solve this

Comment: @TelmoVaz have you copied the same code which i was posted in answer. the modified code is working fine in gcc

Comment: Oh! now I see what you did there. It compiles ok. But now I would like to know why this happens and why my code didn't. If you don't mind, or someone, I would appreciate some detailed explanation or link to get what a liker is and does and why my program didn't work. Thank you for now

Comment: @TelmoVaz In GCC if you compile with your code with the options given  to you will get an error **conflicting types**, why this happening explained in answer. and the second thing **undefined reference to line function**   this is coming because line is not a standard c function. i was comment that function call.this solves your issue.

Comment: @Gangadhar But line() is a function that is within the library, I just didn't paste it here. However the problem still happens under the codeblocks IDE, it seems that is some linker problem.

Comment: @TelmoVaz you can define your own line function. or else you can install your  graphics library in Linux and then you can use line function in GCC.   see this would helpful http://anerdsblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/graphicsh-in-gcc/